# Скачет курсор при срабатывании скрипта

Tags: javascript

Не могу разобраться почему при вставке кавычек в середине текста, курсор уходит в конец текста, как это исправить?

```js
function replaceQuotes(input) {
    input.value = changeQuotes(input.value);
}

function changeQuotes(text) {
    var el = document.createElement("textarea");
    el.innerHTML = text;
    for (var i = 0, l = el.childNodes.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (el.childNodes[i].hasChildNodes() && el.childNodes.length > 1) {
            el.childNodes[i].textContent = changeQuotes(el.childNodes[i].textContent);
        }
        else {
            el.childNodes[i].textContent = el.childNodes[i].textContent.replace(/\x27/g, '\x22').replace(/(\w)\x22(\w)/g, '$1\x27$2').replace(/(^)\x22(\s)/g, '$1»$2').replace(/(^|\s|\()"/g, "$1«").replace(/"(\;|\!|\?|\:|\.|\,|$|\)|\s)/g, "»$1");
        }
    }
    return el.textContent;
}
```

```css
textarea{
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<p>
Пример текста: </br>
"текст" </br>
если этому тексту добавить кавычки</br>
"то курсор переместиться в конец этого текста"</br>
</p>

<textarea onkeyup="replaceQuotes(this)" rows="5" ></textarea>
```

Comment: `input.value = changeQuotes(input.value);` перезаписываете весь текст, после чего устанавливает курсор в конец строки. Тоже самое происходит при `вставке`, когда `копируешь`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function replaceQuotes(textarea){
  let text = textarea.value;
  let index = text.search(/[\"]/);
  
  textarea.value = text.replace(/\x27/g, '\x22').replace(/(\w)\x22(\w)/g, '$1\x27$2').replace(/(^)\x22(\s)/g, '$1»$2').replace(/(^|\s|\()"/g, "$1«").replace(/"(\;|\!|\?|\:|\.|\,|$|\)|\s)/g, "»$1");
  if(index !== -1){
    textarea.selectionStart = textarea.selectionEnd = index + 1; //устанавливаем курсор на место где была кавычка
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeyup="replaceQuotes(this)" rows="5" ></textarea>
```